# How would I extract editors allowed to edit a Word document for use in a SharePoint Workflow?

Tags: .net, api, ms-word, extract

I'm trying to determine the best way to programmatically extract the "Editors" from a Microsoft Word document (docx) - specifically, the list of names (or emails / domain user names) that appear in the list when you add users through the "Review" tab-> "Protect" section, "Restrict Editing" option -> "2. Editing restrictions" section -> "Individuals" list box. If this might somehow be achieved without code, I'm mentioning that SharePoint will be in use to extract this info during a workflow.

I believe I would be able to do it by unzipping the file and searching for the "w:permStart" nodes in the document.xml file, I hesitate to resort to such hacking for the possibility that it could break at some point should Microsoft decide to change things.

The Office API seems to offer a possibility ([Editor Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.editor(v=office.14).aspx)) but I can't test that right now and I'm not positive it's even at the right level of the api, as it's an interface and not an actual property of a document object or similar.

---

### EDIT

The Word 2010 UI lists the names I want to extract under the `Review` tab, in the `Protect` area of the ribbon, through the `Restrict Editing` button (or the `Protect Document` button in Word 2007), which opens the `Restrict Formatting and Editing` panel.

In the second section section of this panel (labeled `2. Editing restrictions`), *if there is no box labeled `Individuals` (Underneath `Exceptions (optional)`)*, check the `Allow only this type of editing in the document` check box (it doesn't matter what is selected in the drop-down following that).

This will enable adding users under the `Exceptions (optional)` section, which is done by clicking the `More users...` link to open a dialog where one types either email addresses (which connect to a Microsoft authentication server) or domain user accounts (if Word is being run on a domain system at the time) separated by a semicolon. These users will be added to a list labeled `Individuals` - this is the list I would like to extract from a word document (pictured below).

This list is used to make "exceptions" to the general document rule specified in the drop down and will only save names that are associated with a given exception range - create a range by adding an email or name to the list, select a block of text (or the whole document), then check the checkbox next to that name to associate it with the selected range. When the document is saved, a reference to that name is added to the underlying document.xml file as the `w:ed` attribute of one or more `w:permStart` elements (one element for each range of text)

I *could* unzip the docx file, parse the document.xml document and extract all the names in those attributes in those elements, but that is very inelegant if there is a Microsoft Word API alternate way of doing it - I would prefer going through the API as it would almost certainly be more maintainable and stable.

[image: Review->Protect->Restrict Editing->Restrictions->Individuals]

Comment: Whereabouts is this data maintained in the Word UI? I can only find 'Related people'...

Comment: @DerekTomes thanks for your question (I tried to indicate that in the first paragraph, but...) please see the edit above for a detailed explanation of how to find (or if necessary, recreate) the list of names in the Word UI

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out where Word hides this data :)

What I did was record a Macro of me adding an editor to the document and reverse engineer it from there.

It seems that Editors are assigned to Ranges. If that part isn't too complicated, this should get you most of the way there:

```
Dim wordApp As New Word.Application
Dim wordDocument As Word.Document = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\MyDoc.docx")

Dim allEditors As Word.Editors = wordDocument.Range(0, 0).Editors
For i As Integer = 1 To allEditors.Count
    Debug.Print(allEditors.Item(i).Name)
Next

wordDocument.Close()
```

Comment: I already looked at the range page twenty times, and dismissed it because I figured I would have to step through every character (i.e. `Range(0,0).Editors`... `Range(1,1).Editors`... `Range(2,2)`...etc), but it looks like it is the only possibility of using the API - does the `(0,0)` parameters somehow refer to all editors? or would I have to loop through every single character range? again - I'm not set up to program this myself at the moment - please update your answer with this info (single call as written or requires loop to find ALL editors) and I will select it. Thanks!

Comment: Range(0,0) is just the beginning of the document. As for the rest, I don't know, I'd suggest some experimentation may be in order. It'll primarily depend on how you're implementing the editor security. If you're implementing it identically across the whole document, testing the first character will probably be all you need to do.

Comment: The goal was to extract all editors that have any 'rights' to modify any part of the document - however, upon further research, it looks like the interop is not supported by Microsoft in a server environment, so I'm going the xml route (which they say they do support)

Comment: That's probably the best way to do it. I've tried to use Word.Interop in a server environment and it's buggy as all hell.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of all the Authors who have revisions in the current document. It's not pretty, but it demonstrates one way of extracting them.

You didn't specify VB.Net or C# but I figure you can convert this to C# if that's your preferred language.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim wordApp As New Word.Application
        Dim wordDocument As Word.Document = wordApp.Documents.Open("c:\MyDoc.docx")
        Dim editors As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        ' Iterate through all the revisions
        For Each r As Word.Revision In wordDocument.Revisions()
            If Not editors.ContainsKey(r.Author.ToString) Then
                editors.Add(r.Author.ToString(), r.Author)
            End If
        Next

        ' List all the unique authors
        For Each s As String In editors.Values
            Debug.Print(s)
        Next
        wordDocument.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: if I understand, this would be the users that have edited the document in the past (revisions) - I am looking for the list of those that are _allowed_ to edit the document (or specified ranges) as exceptions to the "document protection" scheme

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

> ```
>     for (int j = 1; j <= wordDocument.Sections.Count; j++)
>
>             {
>                 for (int i = 1; i <= wordDocument.Sections[j].Range.Editors.Count; i++)
>                 {
>                       //your code here
>                     wordDocument.Sections[j].Range.Editors.Item(i)....
>                 }
>             }
> ```

Comment: Can you expand upon why this would help?